# COUNTIF header row cell Length is less than a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, countif

In column A I want to count all the cells in range B2:J2 that their header row cell LEN is less than 17, basically count all the cells that are highlighted in grey.
Should be possible right?

[image: Example]

Second scenario, one of the cells have #N/A error.

[second scenario example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPGwe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($B$1:$J$1)<17)*(B2:J2<>""))
```

Comment: it returns 6 as in 6 columns that are less than 17, I need to add the part where it checks if the cell in row be is not blank

Comment: That was not in the specifications.

Comment: Works perfectly for my specifications. Thank you Scott! Can I bother to ask in a second scenario one of the cells have #N/A and it returns #N/A, I edited my question and added my second scenario where it should return 2

Comment: Please don't ask a new question here. Create a new post.